# getResources and String Array forces close

Tags: android, arrays

I am new to android programming and it's been some years since I have done any Java programming.

I have declared a string-array in the XML strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="questionSet1_array">
    <item>Question Introduction</item>
    <item> Question1</item>
    <item>Question 2</item>
</string-array>
```

I then start an Activity called `Coastal`. Then, I begin a second activity by pushing a button, starting the activity `Foreshore`.

In activity `Foreshore`, I make the following declaration:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Foreshore extends Activity {

    //globally declare parameters
    private TextView text;
    private EditText answerEntry;
    private Button next;
    Resources res = getResources();
    String [] theQuestions = res.getStringArray(R.array.questionSet1_array);
    //private String theAnswers[];
    //private String answerPasser;
    private int length;
    private int i=0;
```

The lines `Resources res ...`, `String[] ...` cause the program to force close and will not let the activity `Foreshore` commence. When I remove these lines the activity starts correctly.

What is causing this forced close?

Thanks

Comment: Does it still happen if you do this `Resources res = this.getResources();`?

Comment: @keyboardP, tried your suggestion and it still forces the close.

Comment: Just a random thought. Figured the `getResources` might be using the wrong `context` :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't call `getResources()` before your activity class is "officially" instantiated (it's an instance method, and at that point you don't have an instance yet). Move your String array initialization to your `onCreate()`.

Comment: that could be the case, but I have code that works that has `arrayexample = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.impacts);` that is within my `onCreate` but before my `super.onCreate(state);` ah but if it works, then thats good to know.

Comment: @hooraygradschool - Yeah, at that point you're good to go, even if you haven't called `super.onCreate()` .